# CakePHP3.0+Jquery Section Reorderable list

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp-3.0

I am developing an app in CakePHP3.0 that makes use of AJAX, and it's my first go at this, so I would appreciate some feedback on how well this code is written.

This is one part of a larger part of the app, but before I go on to do the rest of AJAX for other parts of the app, I want to make sure my jQuery/AJAX code is optimal and well-structured. Red flags are going up for me because I see a few places where code is copy/pasted, and makes me think it could be better organized/structured.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/0VuwXWbB)'s my code for my view.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/tmuWsi9d)'s the code for my controller.

[Here](http://screencast.com/t/jslu6H7f6h)'s what it looks like in action.

I'm looking for any improvements/optimizations/structuring to the code I can make, both the view and controller. Is there anything I should maybe move to the model layer? Any way to optimize my queries? Maybe I should implement a technique or feature to improve the performance? I also plan on adding some code for an editing button with AJAX and will update this with the new code when I do that. Hopefully this is a fair ask and posting working code and asking for help isn't a bad thing!

Comment: sugest we move this to CodeReview

Comment: There's no code to review. This question would be closed as off-topic on [codereview.se].

Comment: If I am asking this in the wrong place, or even the wrong site, let me know where I should go!

Comment: Also the code for review is on the pastebin links, should it be embedded into the post? Since there's nothing in specific that I can create a snippet from(since it's a question about code efficiency/structure), I pasted the whole file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a good structure and organized you shuold be read [good practices jquery](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/09/16/jquery-examples-and-best-practices/), and you can look for more information about good pactices javascript o jquery like you want. you can get the result you expect, maybe you can read about clean code.

What I have been using for myself that worked in practice already is to write your jQuery code in plugin format. This way making it reusable for other projects if needed, cutting down on code duplication, forcing you to encapsulate change and most of all it becomes open for extension but closed for modification - so all of those great practices that make up a clean code base.

```
(function($){
    var PluginName = function(element)
    {
        var elem = $(element);
        var obj = this;

        var settings = $.extend({
            someSetting: "someValue"
        });

        this.func1 = function(someArgument)
        {
            some code
        };

        this.func2 = function()
        {
            some more code
        };
    };

    $.fn.pluginName= function()
    {
        return this.each(function()
        {
            var element = $(this);
            if (element.data('pluginName')) return;
            var pluginName = new PluginName(this);
            element.data('pluginName', pluginName);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```